# How to increment a List Name?

Tags: c#, loops, increment

I will first show you my code because I'm having a hard time finding words to explain what I want, I have a List of Points which contains coordinates`List<PointF> points;`, they are 20 coordinates to be exact. I want to separate those 20 points into 4 List of Points. This are my 4 List of Points:

```
        List<PointF> Col1 = new List<PointF>();
        List<PointF> Col2 = new List<PointF>();
        List<PointF> Col3 = new List<PointF>();
        List<PointF> Col4 = new List<PointF>();
```

This is my code :

```
        int loop = 1;
        while (loop <= 20) 
        {
            var identifier = 1;
            if (loop % 5 == 0)
            {
                identifier++;
            }
            else 
            {//Here is what I'm talking about, if I want it to be like Col1 + identifier.ToString(), something like that
                Col.Add(new PointF(points.ElementAt(loop - 1).X, points.ElementAt(loop - 1).Y));   
            }
        }
```

What i want to do is if my loop is already at 5 I want my **Col1.add** to be "Col2.add" and if my loop is equal to 10, I want my **Col2.add** to be "Col3.add" and if my loop is equal to 15, I want my **Col3.add** to be "Col4.add". I dont know how to say this but, I want to increment my List names.

I want something like this, but it is with **20 PictureBox** and not with variables.

```
                for (int x = 1; x <= ExtractedBoxes.Count(); x++)
            {
                ((PictureBox)this.Controls["pictureBox" + x.ToString()]).Image = ExtractedBoxes[x - 1];
            }
```

Comment: You could use a Dictionary<string, List<PointF>>. MSDN reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply but, is there an easier way like the second last code I have given in my question? It seems to be so complicated

Comment: That's exactly what @AdrianFaciu's answer would do.  You need to put your 4 lists into another collection so that you can easily switch between them.

Comment: I got it know because of the sample code @codeCaster made, but I am still thankful for you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array may be a better solution:

```
List<PointF>[] lists = {new List<PointF>(), new List<PointF>(), new List<PointF>(), new List<PointF>()};

for(int i=0;i<20;i++) lists[i/5].Add(points[i]);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with a `Dictionary<int, List<PointF>>` as [suggested by @Adrian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21680572/how-to-increment-a-list-name#comment32774316_21680572):

```
var result = new Dictionary<int, List<PointF>>();
int identifier = 0;
result[identifier] = new List<PointF>();

for (int loop = 0; loop < 19; loop++) 
{
    if ((loop - 1) % 5 == 0)
    {
        result[++identifier] = new List<PointF>();
    }

    result[identifier].Add(points[loop]);       
}
```

See [Split List into Sublists with LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419019/split-list-into-sublists-with-linq) for an alternative.

Comment: If I want to sort my first result, is this correct? result[1].OrderBy(c => c.Y).ToList();

Comment: I know this is the best way, but I'm having a hard time using this kind of method in c#. I'm only processing 20 Points so I guess it is okay if I used @ic3b3rg's way, which is easier to understand for me. But anyway, thanks alot!